# PHP Post Empty Upon Request

Tags: php, html

I can't work out why this isn't working. I'm sure it's probably something small but I keep scratching my head. Below are my HTML and PHP.

**form.html**

```
<form action="result" method="post">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hello">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**result.php** *(.htaccess is set to allow without .PHP and I receive the same issue when including .PHP in the action)*

```
<?php

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
     echo "POST<br>";
  }
                                
  print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Submitting the form sends you to result.php and POST is displayed, but `$_POST` is empty.

**EDIT**: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

Cheers in advance.

Comment: `action="result.php"` instead of `action="result"` in `<form action="result.php" method="post">`

Comment: Show us what yout .htaccess actually contains then. This sounds like the typical case where you lose the post data due to an _external_ redirect, which the browser follows by making a _GET_ request now.

Comment: Hi @CBroe I've included the .htaccess - cheers for your help so far!

Comment: Hey @Chilarai, I've tried that and it, unfortunately, doesn't make a difference. I think CBroe could be on the right tracks with the .htaccess

Comment: [How to preserve POST data via ajax request after a .htaccess redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13886631/2943403)

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa I'm really grateful for the reply. The answer to the question you've just commented leads me to another question - how would one go about changing it to a rewrite and not a redirect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @mickmackusa and @CBroe it was determined that the issue was with the `.htaccess` file.

It was redirecting instead of rewriting when removing the .PHP extension. The solution was to instead change the `.htaccess` to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Thanks everyone for your help.